# How to convert each row in Pandas DF to 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe with `785` columns (`784` columns and `1` column as a label).

I wanna use CNN to train a model on it, therfore I should convert each row if the dataframe to "image": `(28x28x1)` (28x28=784), so a new dataframe will contain only 2 columns.

How can I can it?

The idead is on the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is an example of 4 columns and a label.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_path = './example.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(csv_path)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column', 'label'])

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    a = []
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
        if j == 'label':
            label = column
            break
        a.append(column)
    img = np.array(a).reshape(2, 2)
    label = column
    df_new.loc[i] = [img, label]

df_new.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: It returns DatarFame with (1, 2) shape ...

Comment: I added the screenshot of result.csv, so isn't it as you expect?

Comment: Yes it is. Hmm...

Comment: So iI find decision X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)

Answer (score 0):

X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)

Answer (score 0):

If you look for something like `[[1,2,3,4]]`, you can use the code below. If you need the array in the format of `[[1,2], [3,4]]`, then change the reshape method as `np.reshape(arr, (2, 2))`. `df` is the original dataframe with 784 feature and label columns.

First, get all columns except the label:

```
columns = df.columns.to_list()
columns.remove('label')
```

Then, use the apply method to convert the `df` to the format you need:

```
def arrayize(df):
    arr = df.to_numpy()
    arr = arr.astype(int)
    arr = np.reshape(arr, (-1, 4))
    
    return arr

df["numpy_col"] = df[columns].apply(arrayize, axis=1)
```

I haven't run the code to test it, so you may need to check it.